# Pivottable - "evaluate calculated members from olap server in filters" keeps turning off

Tags: excel, pivot-table, cube

I have a number of pivottables in excel 2013 that I select the pivottable options and under the Totals & Filter tab I set to the "evaluate calculated members from olap server in filters" to be ticked on. I find that if I save and close the workbook then reopen it the evaluate calculated members from olap server in filters option has been deactivated. Has anyone had this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

I found that creating a new spreadsheet seemed to do the trick. There must of been something broken in the old file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, but found that changing the PivotTable setting on the Display tab to *not* Show Row Values solved the issue for me. It also stopped Slicers from disappearing between closing and opening the workbook.